# reading xstream generated xml into .net

Tags: c#, java, .net, xml-serialization, xstream

We'd like to generate xml using [xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/) implemented with java.  We'd then like to consume that xml in a .net application and have it deserialized into c# classes.

has anyone had success in doing this? is there a framework available on the C# side that will make it easier and more robust than something we'd have to roll-up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a special framework.  You can do it with the XmlSerialization namespace that is builtin to .NET.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2007/10/10/date-and-time-values-and-xstream-interop.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [xstream-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/xstream-dot-net/)